# Laravel file upload API using Postman

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, postman, multifile-uploader

I have the following code in my controller:

```
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
       $files = $request->file('uploads');
       if(!empty($files)) {
           foreach($files as $file) {
               Storage::put($file-getClientOriginalName(),file_get_contents($file));
        }
    }
```

Which is called via an `api.php` in `routes`:

```
Route::post('/upload', [ 'uses' => 'UploadController@upload' ]);
```

I am using postman to test my application.

**Header:**

[image]

**Body:**

[image]

**Raw:**

> POST /scotic/public/api/upload HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1:80
>   Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Postman-Token: 0caf7349-5c91-e5f1-766f-72a3f1e33900
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploads[]"; filename="banana.png" Content-Type:
>   image/png  png data goes here..
>   ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--

The `$files` is empty upon uploading the file. What am i doing wrong?

After a bit of digging, I got my uploader working without postman, I noticed that the '--boundary' was missing from the `Content-Type` in postman. The LHS works, RHS(postman) does not work.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try implementing via base64 data.

Comment: I compared the postman with web-browser it seems that '--boundary' is missing in postman - any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue was that I was explicitly specifying the `Content-Type` in postman.

According to one of the answers from this [post](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/191):

There is no need to add a content-type header manually. You are overriding the value set by Postman. Just select form-data in POST request and send your request to see if it works.

Comment: Yes, I just removed the Content-Type from the header in the input and it worked. I would suggest you to use Wireshark to capture the TCP packets and troubleshoot.

Comment: Any chance you used guzzle later on to make the actual post ? I've got the same case as you with a post including file and data. It works with Postman thanks to your post but I can't get it to work with the code. Using GuzzleHttp to make the request