# getting error while uploading file using postman

Tags: laravel, file-upload, postman

I'm trying to upload an image file . When i am calling my API to upload file using postman , getting error like `Fatal error: Call to a member function file() on array`.

I could not post this file to my Laravel controller .How to post files in Laravel. Anyone could help me to solve this issue?

Here is my controller function,

```
public function edit(Request $request){

    $request = $request->input();
    if(empty($request)) {
        $request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
    }

    $to_return = array();

    $file = $request->file('files'); 
}
```

at this line `$file = $request->file('files');` getting fatal error.

Comment: code indentation improvement

Answer (score 0):

set method as post .. and at body ... change to option from `form data` to `w-xxx-formurlencod` ... and try ..

Comment: if i change the option from form data to w-xxx-formurlencod, how can i browse file from  location?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to file uploads with Postman and Laravel, simply remove the `Content-Type` header setting in Postman.

Comment: i wont set any header

Comment: @SikhaA: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633582/laravel-file-upload-api-using-postman)

Answer (score 0):

set method as post

[image]

and at body ... select the radio that shows url encoded

[image]

Answer (score 0):

see an image ... click on text set it as flie

[image]